# Bash script written in vim works differently than in the terminal! WHY?

Tags: bash, curl, scripting, quotes, double-quotes

The idea is the bash script that enumerates internal ports (SSRF) of a website using ports in the "common_ports.txt" file and outputs the port and "content-length" of each port accordingly.

That is curl request:

```sh
$ curl -Is "http://10.10.182.210:8000/attack?port=5000"
 HTTP/1.0 200 OK 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 1035
 Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.9
 Date: Sat, 16 Oct 2021 13:02:27 GMT
```

To get the content length I have used grep:

```sh
$ curl -Is "http://10.10.182.210:8000/attack?port=5000" | grep  "Content-Length"
  Content-Length: 1035
```

Till now everything was ok. But when I wrote it in vim to automate the process I got weird output.

This is my full bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file="./common_ports.txt"


while IFS= read -r  line 
do
        response=$(curl -Is "http://10.10.182.210:8000/attack?port=$line")
         
        len=$(echo $response | grep  "Content-Length:")
        echo "$len"
done < "$file"
```

An THIS IS THE OUTPUT:

```sh
$ ./script.sh
 Date: Sat, 16 Oct 2021 13:10:35 GMT9-8
 Date: Sat, 16 Oct 2021 13:10:36 GMT9-8
^C
```

It outputs the last line of the `response` variable. Could anyone explain why??
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `$response` inside double quotes.

```sh
len=$(echo "$response" | grep  "Content-Length:")
```